# How to reduce tensorflow dataset input pipeline host device (cpu) time (currently ~40%)?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, profiling, tensorboard, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to replicate the resnet18 paper. Before running this on the full Image Net dataset on disk, I'm doing some evaluation runs with the publicly available `imagenette/320px` dataset from TFDS (much much smaller subset of imagenet with 10 classes, already in `.tfrecord` format._

**Note**: the full notebook to do training and tracing is available here: [resnet18_baseline.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/ntakouris/1a17cf3148a3d775fde85cac2bfd52a4/resnet18_baseline.ipynb) Just switch to a `GPU` runtime and run all the cells. It's already set-up with tensorboard profiling on the second batch. (You can use TPU as well, but some `keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing` layers do not support TPU ops yet and you have to enable soft device placement. Please use a GPU).

### Input Operations

1. read images from the input dataset. These images usually have got different dimensions and we need some crop function because input tensors can **not** have different dimensions for batching. Therefore, for training I use random crop and for testing/validation datasets a center crop.

```py
random_crop_layer = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomCrop(224, 224)
center_crop_layer = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.CenterCrop(224, 224)

@tf.function(experimental_relax_shapes=True) # avoid retracing
def train_crop_fn(x, y):
  return random_crop_layer(x), y

@tf.function(experimental_relax_shapes=True)
def eval_crop_fn(x, y):
  return center_crop_layer(x), y
```

2. Perform some simple preprocessing/augmentations to the input data. These include rescaling to 0-1 and also scaling based on mean and stdev of the rgb colours on imagenet. Also, random

```py
rescaling_layer = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)

train_preproc = keras.Sequential([
  rescaling_layer
])

# from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/image_classification/preprocessing.py
# Calculated from the ImageNet training set
MEAN_RGB = (0.485 , 0.456, 0.406)
STDDEV_RGB = (0.229, 0.224, 0.225)

@tf.function
def z_score_scale(x):
  return (x - MEAN_RGB) / STDDEV_RGB

@tf.function
def train_preproc_fn(x, y):
  return z_score_scale(train_preproc(x)), y

@tf.function
def eval_preproc_fn(x, y):
  return z_score_scale(eval_preproc(x)), y
```

### Input Pipeline

```py
def get_input_pipeline(input_ds, bs, crop_fn, augmentation_fn):
  ret_ds = (
      input_ds
      .batch(1) # pre-crop are different dimensions and can't be batched
      .map(crop_fn, 
          num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
      .unbatch()
      .batch(bs)
      .map(augmentation_fn, # augmentations can be batched though.
          num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
  )

  return ret_ds

# dataset loading
def load_imagenette():
  train_ds, ds_info = tfds.load('imagenette/320px', split='train', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)
  valid_ds = tfds.load('imagenette/320px', split='validation', as_supervised=True)

  return train_ds, valid_ds, valid_ds, ds_info.features['label'].num_classes

# pipeline construction
train_ds, valid_ds, test_ds, num_classes = load_imagenette()

# datasets used for training (notice that I use prefetch here)
train_samples = get_input_pipeline(train_ds, BS, train_crop_fn, train_preproc_fn).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
valid_samples = get_input_pipeline(valid_ds, BS, eval_crop_fn, eval_preproc_fn).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
test_samples = get_input_pipeline(test_ds, BS, eval_crop_fn, eval_preproc_fn).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

### Training and Profiling

I use tensorboard profiler to check the second batch size and I get a warning that this is highly input bound, with about 40% of processing wasted on inputs.

For a classic resnet18 model, you can drive the batch size up to 768 without getting a OOM error, which is what I use. A single step with bs 256 takes about 2-3 seconds.

I also get a warning that `on_train_batch_size_end` is slow, at around ~1.5 seconds, compared to the 1s batch time.

The model training code is very simple keras:

```py
model.fit(
        train_samples,
        validation_data=valid_samples,
        epochs=100,
        batch_size=BS,
        use_multiprocessing=True
        callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, model_checkpoint_callback, early_stop_callback, reduce_lr_callback]
)
```

and the callbacks are specified as:

```py
log_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'logs')
tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, update_freq="epoch", profile_batch=2)

reduce_lr_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=5, min_lr=0.001, verbose=1)

model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.4f}.h5',
                                              monitor='val_loss',
                                              verbose=1,
                                              save_best_only=True)

early_stop_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15)
```

Lastly, here are some sample tensorboard profiling screenshots. I can't figure out how to make this run faster:

[image: input pipeline analysis]

[image: tensorboard profiling tip]